# Am I need to use @Access=FIELD annotation with many-to-one relationship?

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, getter, hibernate-onetomany

I have entities which are divided into categories. Each entity can belong to many categories, so I have one to many association.

Is it ORM-ed correctly below:

```
@OneToMany
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
private Set<Category> parents = new HashSet<Category>();
public Set<Category> getParents() {
    return parents;
}
public boolean addParent(Category parent) {
    return parents.add(parent);
}
public boolean removeParent(Category parent) {
    return parents.remove(parent);
}
```

My specific question is am I need to use @Access annotation or not? If I won't use it then how Hibernate will know not to map `getParents` getter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know whether or not you need the `@Access(AccessType.FIELD)` annotation, because this depends on some defaults (see below).
But if you use Field access type (by default or by `@Access(AccessType.FIELD)`) then 
Hibernate will access the FIELD directly and not use the getter or setter!

See [Hibernate Reference, chapter 5.1.4.1.2. Access type](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/), for more details about the access type determination algorithm.

> By default the access type of a class hierarchy is defined by the position of the @Id or @EmbeddedId annotations. If these annotations are on a field, then only fields are considered for persistence and the state is accessed via the field. If there annotations are on a getter, then only the getters are considered for persistence and the state is accessed via the getter/setter. That works well in practice and is the recommended approach.

Comment: So how do you know I need no `@Access` annotation while you don't know where I put my `@Id`?

Comment: @Suzan Cioc: yes you are right. Next time post the complete relevant code, so that one can answerer without spending to much free time.

Comment: I couldn't knew what was relevant in this case, sorry.